# Combining a parameter argument inside an echo

Tags: mysql, variable, arguments, echo, parameter

I use the following script to do the following actions in my environment:

1. Creating an Nginx site conf.
2. Creating a corresponding Let'sEncrypt SSL certificate.
3. Creating a symlink between my `sites-default` dir to my site conf.
4. Restarting the server.

### My code:

```
#!/bin/sh
for domain; do
    > "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf" cat <<EOF
        server {
            root /var/www/html/${DOMAIN};
            server_name ${DOMAIN} www.${DOMAIN};

            location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
            }

            location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
                try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }

            location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
                expires 365d;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
    EOF
    sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain} /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
    #########################################################################
    certbot --nginx -d ${DOMAIN} -d www.${DOMAIN}
done
systemctl restart nginx.service # Create Webapp Substrate.
```

### How and why I want to improve this code:

Where the long row of hashmarks, I want to insert the following command:

```
echo 'create database ${DOMAIN}; create user "${DOMAIN}"@"localhost" identified by "mypassword"; grant all privileges on ${DOMAIN}.* to ${DOMAIN};' | mysql -u root -p
```

Adding this command will change the script to do 5 steps instead 4:

1. Creates an Nginx site conf.
2. Creates a corresponding Let'sEncrypt SSL certificate.
3. Creating a symlink between my `sites-default` dir to my site conf.
4. **Adding an all privileged, and authenticated DB user suitable only for localhost, with a DB with the same name.**
5. Restarting the server.

---

### My question:

As you can see, I used my parameter `${DOMAIN}` inside the `echo`. I did that because I **must** pass the same argument there as well, otherwise, the DB username and it's associated DB both won't fit my site conf and my Wordpress based site won't boot.

**Is this operation logical in Bash or you would take another approach?**

To clarify, I ask this to understand if passing arguments based on parameters is valid when the parameter is inside an `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without `echo`:

```
mysql -u root -ppass <<EOF
  create database ${DOMAIN};
  create user "${DOMAIN}"@"localhost" identified by "mypassword";
  grant all privileges on ${DOMAIN}.* to ${DOMAIN};
EOF
```

And see topic [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Deep thanks Egor. Is there a way to write or paste `mypassword` on place, without writing anything like `mypassword` or `Mps59azopp1`? inside my script? (Of course, `Mps59azopp1` isn't really my password, it's just a random example I made up to demonstrate that I prefer not to keep my DB particular password inside my script.

Comment: One possible solution is to keep it `mypassword` and change it manually after the script finished running with `SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name-here'@'hostname-name-here' = PASSWORD('new-password-here');` while the user-name is what I've putted in `$domain`.

Comment: @Arcticooling, you can leave `-p` without a `password` string, and when executing the script, it will ask for a password. Try to test this approach

Comment: So instead `identified by "mypassword";` it becomes `identified by -p;`?

Comment: see this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471757/store-mysql-password-in-bash-script

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're asking about is [Bash parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). The `echo` command doesn't play a role here. It looks like you're using [single-quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html) instead of [double-quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes), which suppresses parameter substitution in the string. Just use double-quotes instead of single-quotes and use backslashes to escape any double-quotes that you want included in the string, e.g.:

```
echo "create database ${DOMAIN}; create user \"${DOMAIN}\"@\"localhost\" identified by \"mypassword\"; grant all privileges on ${DOMAIN}.* to ${DOMAIN};"
```